# Initialize a struct in C using {}

Tags: c, struct, initialization

In the marked line I get an error `Error - expected expression`

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct list_head {
    struct list_head *next, *prev;
};

struct program_struct {
    const char *name;
    struct list_head node;
};
typedef struct program_struct program_t;

struct task_t {
    program_t blocked_list;
};

int main() {

    struct task_t *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
    p->blocked_list.name = NULL;
    p->blocked_list.node = {&(p->blocked_list.node), &(p->blocked_list.node)}; //error

    return 0;
}
```

I know I can replace this line with

```
p->blocked_list.node.next = &(p->blocked_list.node);
p->blocked_list.node.prev = &(p->blocked_list.node);
```

But can I make it work using `{}` like I tried in the first piece of code?

Comment: Even though you can use a compound literal for this, _there is no reason to do so_. Instead use the most readable form, which is two rows: `p->blocked_list.node.next = &p->blocked_list.node; p->blocked_list.node.prev = &p->blocked_list.node;` This is the clearest form and therefore the one preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialization is allowed only when you define a variable. So, you can't use initializers in assignment.
You can instead use C99's [compound literals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2.3/gcc/Compound-Literals.html):

```
p->blocked_list.node = (struct list_head) {&(p->blocked_list.node), &(p->blocked_list.node)}; //error
```

Comment: Please note that the compound literal defined by doing `(struct list_head) {..}` lives on until the current scope is left. To have it be deallocated immediately after the assignment just wrap the whole assignment statement into a new scope by enclosing it into braces `{...}`.